# could a c# console app also act as a class library?

Tags: c#, .net

Normally it doesn't make sense to do it this way.

That said, could a c# console app also act as a class library?

Comment: What did you try so far? Create another project as windows application or web application, reference your console app and use some public classes of it and check if it works as expected ;-)

Comment: @Davide Piras: I tried it on an older version of VS.  I'm *still* getting used to MS tools being as capable as they are now.  Thought I'd ask first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can. As long as it has public types or `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo(...)]`.

In VS2005 the IDE was reluctant to allow you to reference an exe, but this is no longer the case. Just add a reference and specify the exe (or the project).

Ultimately, it is just an assembly; the PE header / loader is minimal and is not of significant note to the file, hence the fact of it being an exe is virtually irrelevant.

Note that `Main()` (the entry-point) won't be invoked when using an exe as a library.

Comment: I thought that this should be the case.  Once bitten though.  ty.  +1.All().

Answer (score 3):

It does, simply reference it in another project.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to reference a console application and use the public classes within it.  However while technically functional it wouldn't be considered best practice.

A better solution would be to have the following:

- MyClassLibrary.dll

that is referenced by:

- MyConsoleApp.exe
- MyOtherConsoleApp.exe
- MyOtherClassLibrary.exe

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: yes. The only one difference is that console application has an entry point (the Main method) and may be executed separately.